# Build array of the contents of the working directory in perl

Tags: perl, directory-structure, working-directory

I am working on a script which utilizes files in surrounding directories using a path such as

```
"./dir/file.txt"
```

This works fine, as long as the working directory is the one containing the script. However the script is going out to multiple users and some people may not change their working directory and run the script by typing its entire path like this:

```
./path/to/script/my_script.pl
```

This poses a problem as when the script tries to access ./dir/file.txt it is looking for the /dir directory in the home directory, and of course, it can't fine it.

I am trying to utilize readdir and chdir to correct the directory if it isn't the right one, here is what I have so far:

```
my $working_directory = $ENV{PWD};
print "Working directory: $working_directory\n";       #accurately prints working directory
my @directory = readdir $working_directory;            #crashes script

if (!("my_script.pl" ~~ @directory)){                  #if my_script.pl isnt in @directoryies, do this
    print "Adjusting directory so I work\n";
    print "Your old directory: $ENV{PWD}\n";
    chdir $ENV{HOME};                                  #make the directory home
    chdir "./path/to/script/my_script.pl";             #make the directory correct
    print "Your new directory: $ENV{PWD}\n";
}
```

The line containing readdir crashes my script with the following error

> Bad symbol for dirhandle at ./path/to/script/my_script.pl line 250.

which I find very strange because I am running this from the home directory which prints out properly right beforehand and contains nothing  to do with the "bad symbol"

I'm open to any solutions

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `readdir` operates with a directory handle, not a path on a string. You need to do something like:

```
opendir(my $dh, $working_directory) || die "can't opendir: $!";
my @directory = readdir($dh);
```

Check perldoc for both [`readdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) and [`opendir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/opendir.html).

Comment: Thanks! that was very simple and a little stupid on my part. I also learned now that chdir wont actually change the directory of the parent process which is what I need. I have adjusted my strategy so that the required files can be referenced by their path which is "./" by default. if the working directory does not contain my_script.pl ./ will change to the necessary path to find those files.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going about this the wrong way. If you're looking for a file that's travelling with your script, then what you probably should consider is the `FindBin` module - that lets you figure out the path to your script, for use in path links.

So e.g.

```
use FindBin;
my $script_path = $FindBin::Bin; 

open ( my $input, '<', "$script_path/dir/file.txt" ) or warn $!;
```

That way you don't have to faff about with `chdir` and `readdir` etc.